# Adding tinyMCE content to serialized array (WordPress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I have a HTML form on the front end of my (WordPress) website which has the potential to display a TinyMCE field.

The form itself is fully customisable by the WP Admin and therefore the ID/name of the tinyMCE field could be anything.

When the form is submitted, I am running some jQuery to validate the fields (i.e. any that are configured to be required must have content). If validation fails, an alert is displayed, otherwise the form is submitted.

However I have a problem getting this to work with when a tinyMCE field is used in that I need to get the content of the field in my JS file and then validate it within my PHP validation function.

For the form itself, I am simply serializing the data. What I now need to do is add the input ID of the tinyMCE field and its content to that array.

```js
var $form      = $("#myform");
var formData   = $("#myform").serialize();

var mceContent;

var tinymceActive = (typeof tinyMCE != 'undefined') && tinyMCE.activeEditor && ! tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden();

if (tinymceActive) {
    mceContent = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
}
```

So I have `formData` as my serialized array, and `mceContent` contains the editors content, but how do I get the editor field name and its content into `formData`? I know I can retrieve the editors name with `tinymce.editors[0].id` but I cannot for the life of me add `{tinymce.editors[0].id : mceContent}` into the `formData` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery serialize function works on the form fields in your form ... when it comes to TinyMCE the editor "hides" the underlying `<textarea>` and when you call `serialize()` and submit the form via JavaScript the `<textarea>` is empty.

Before serializing/submitting the form, call something like `tinyMCE.activeEditor.triggerSave()` or `tinyMCE.get('yourEditorId').triggerSave()` - this will force TinyMCE to update the value of the underlying `<textarea>` so that jQuery's serialize function will properly serialize the value of the `<textarea>` as a natural part of the form.

Comment: `tinyMCE.activeEditor.triggerSave()` returned an unknown function error but `tinyMCE.triggerSave()` did the job.
Thank you!